# CMake error: "INSTALL TARGETS - target Xxx has RESOURCE files but no RESOURCE DESTINATION." when building a bundle on OS X

Tags: macos, cmake

We are building an application on OS X, the build management being implemented in CMake.
In the CMakeLists.txt of the application, the target is added as:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_RESOURCES}
    main.mm
)
```

With `${PROJECT_NAME}_RESOURCES` variable listing the xib and image files. We also set the target properties and configure the installation as follows:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
                      VERSION "${VERSION}"
                      SOVERSION "${SOVERSION}"
                      RESOURCE "${${PROJECT_NAME}_RESOURCES}"
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        BUNDLE DESTINATION ${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
)
```

Quoting the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/install.html?highlight=install#installing-targets) (emphasis mine):

> The PRIVATE_HEADER, PUBLIC_HEADER, and RESOURCE arguments cause
>   subsequent properties to be applied to installing a FRAMEWORK shared
>   library target’s associated files on non-Apple platforms. **Rules
>   defined by these arguments are ignored on Apple platforms** because the
>   associated files are installed into the appropriate locations inside
>   the framework folder.

So we would understand that specifing a `RESOURCE` argument to `install()` would be ignored in our situation. Yet CMake issues this message (in red):

> INSTALL TARGETS - target Xxx has RESOURCE files but no RESOURCE
>   DESTINATION.

---

**EDIT**: Setting a value for `RESOURCE DESTINATION` in the `install()` command disables the message. In this case, the resources are still copied in the right place into the application bundle, but they are also copied into the provided value.

Is there at least a way to turn off this message without introducing copies that are useless on OS X ?

Comment: Did you try to use `RESOURCE DESTINATION`? Documentation can be not strictly correct.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, it does shut up the message as one would expect. But the documentation is correct in the sense that the given value is disregarded (the resources are always installed in the same folder of the generated bundle on Apple platform [tested with OS X]). So it seems the warning is just a nuisance: it encourages the developer to set a value somewhere, in a situation where this value will be ignored (which is confusing).

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is actually even worse: if this value is set, when installing the project the resources are still copied in the right directory of the application bundle (what is wanted on OS X). But they are also copied in the value set for DESTINATION. The value needs to be set to shut up the warning, but it then induces some dummy file copy operations...

Comment: Hmm, so it seems to be a bug in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You could be right about that: I [opened a ticket](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15676), we'll see!

Comment: I get the same error/warning on a buildbot with CMake 3.19.8, but on my local machine the same project configures without this warning using CMake 3.22.1. So I reckon this issue is now fixed.